# the floating hint of a hook

Tags: phrase-meaning

> --and now this summer his anthems of Louisiana street life throb out the windows of speeding cars, **the floating hint of a hook giving
>   away the track**, drowning in cardboard subwoofer fuzz, trunks and
>   rearview mirrors.

(BEYOND THE BREACH  08/24/15 • ESPN THE MAGAZINE)

What does **the bold part** mean?  Is **"a hook"** as a short hard blow in boxing? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case the definition of [**hook**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hook) is musical, though it does have the same basic meaning as definition 1b on the linked page.

> hook (n): 1b. something intended to attract and ensnare

It means a distinctive passage of music that catches your attention and draws you to listen to the song.  The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_(music)) about musical hooks explains them in greater detail.

A "floating hint of a hook giving away the track" means that the musical hook was barely heard, but sufficiently distinctive that the track (particular song) was identifiable.